# Redirecting to wrong URL Django

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

I've been working on a Django project that has multiple types of users. Hence, I'm creating more than one signup page, one for each type of user. I created one page for users to chose if they want to sign up as a mentor or a student so they can later be given a right form. 
However, my urls don't work properly and both 'register' and 'register_student' urls take me to the view I created for register. What am I doing wrong?

My register/urls.py :

```
    urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.register, name='register'),
       path('', views.student_register, name='student_register'),
 ]
```

My register/templates/register/register.html

```
    {% block content %}
       <h2>Sign up</h2>
       <p class="lead">Select below the type of account you want to create</p>
        <a href="{% url 'student_register' %}" class="btn btn-student btn-lg" 
         role="button">I'm a student</a>
    {% endblock %}
```

My register/views.py

```
    def register(request):
        return render(request, "register/register.html")

    def student_register(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            student_form = StudentRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if student_form.is_valid():
                user = student_form.save(commit=False)
                user.is_student = True
                user.save()
        else:
            student_form = StudentRegisterForm()
        return render(request, "register/student_register.html", {"student_form": student_form})
```

And my app's ursl:
mentorapp/mentorapp/urls:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), # gives access to django log-in/out pages
       path('mainpage/', include('mainpage.urls')),
       path('register/', include('register.urls')),
       path('student_register/', include('register.urls')),
  ]
```

localhost:8000/register shows the 'register.html' page and when I click on 'I'm a student' url changes to localhost:8000/register_student but it stays on the same html page - 'register.html', and it doesn't render the right view containing the student registration form. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should give the different paths for each url on register/urls.py. @natpas

Comment: @EliakinCosta that helped. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome @natpas

Answer (score 0):

From django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request):

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first
>   one that matches the requested URL.

The problem is: how you are defining the same urls for both paths with `register/urls.py`, the url dispatcher resolves the first one and neves looks for the other.

**e.g.**

```
urlpatterns = [
       path('register', views.register, name='register'),
       path('register_student', views.student_register, name='student_register'),
 ]
```